# Correlating two MySQL tables according to time

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following tables

```
Actions: actionID, time, type
States: stateID, time, type
```

I need to find out what was the current state at the time the actions were performed.

So I started up with something like

```
SELECT actions.actionID, states.stateID
FROM actions, states
WHERE states.time < actions.time
```

This gives me a result table with ALL the states that existed before a given action took place. But I need only the LAST state before the action.

So I need some kind of GROUP BY based on max(states.stateID) but I honestly can't figure out how to solve this one !

**EDIT**

So if actions table contains this:

```
actionID  time                   type
1         '2012-10-30 02:05:00'  100
2         '2012-10-30 02:11:00'  200
```

And states table contains this:

```
stateID  time                   type
11       '2012-10-30 02:00:00'  A
12       '2012-10-30 02:10:00'  B
13       '2012-10-30 02:15:00'  A
```

I would like the following result:

```
actionID  stateID
1         11          // Because before action 1, the state that prevailed was 11
2         12          // Because before action 2, the state that prevailed was 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select t.actionID,t.stateID,a.type action_type,s.type state_type  from 

(SELECT actions.actionID,max(states.stateID) stateID
FROM actions, states
WHERE states.time < actions.time
group by actions.actionID)as t

join 

actions a on t.actionID=a.actionID

join

states s on t.stateID=s.stateID
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75162/26)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above queries give the right result. See edit for an example of what I woule like.

Comment: I have edted the query pls check

Comment: This indeed works. Thanks ! But then, I tried outputting the action and state types as well and got mismatched results : type of stateID 11 was good but type of stateID 12 was not. As if max(states.stateID) applies only to stateID and now to entire state row.

Comment: any idea as to how I can also output the types using the same query ? Thnx

Comment: try the updated query to get type fields from actions and states table

Comment: Yep, this works just fine ! Now last question: is the use of a sub-query the only way to achieve this ? From all that I've learned about MySQL in the past year, I was under the impression that suq-queries were not good performance wise because derived tables didn't have indexes.

Comment: If your data derieved from a subquery is not huge then this works fine.If there is huge data you can go for temp table and put the result init and create index and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look at temp tables.